# How to tell if tilelayer is fully visible

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In my app I'm switching tilelayer opacities to create animation. The problem is, the tilelayer doesn't have `visible` (or something similar) event, which should trigger, once all tiles are visible on page. So now often happens that the preloaded layer's tiles are not fully visible and when I hide the layer bellow, the animation "blinks".

**Note**: tileLayers are retrieved and appended to map, so I'm changing only opacity

What I wan't to achive:

```
preloadedLayer.setOpacity(1);
// wait till preloadedLayer is fully visible
visibleLayer.setOpacity(0);
```

Any idea, how to tell if tiles are fully loaded?

**Edit**

[load](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#tilelayer-load) event doesn't trigger when tileLayer is already appended to map and 
 just the layer's opacity is changed.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the `load` event doesn't fire? If you suspect there's a race condition involving a `setOpacity()` call and the `load` event, then please document it and send a bug report.

Comment: The `load` event is triggering, but only when I use `map.add()` or `tileLayer.addTo()`. When I'm changing the opacity of the already appended tileLayer with `tileLayer.setOpacity()` method, the `load` event is not triggered.

Comment: Opacity changes are CSS-driven, and therefore instantaneous. (Or, at worst, they take one render frame to take full effect)

Comment: Wait, are you referring to the fade-in animation when tiles are being loaded?

Comment: No, the animations are turned off. I solved the blinking issue by hiding the tileLayers with `display: none` and showing them with `display: block` with `jQuery`. It seems to be quicker.